# PHP DOMElement appendChild get DOMException Wrong Document Error

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, domdocument

I want to copy `<w:p>` tags from an XML document into another one. Both XML documents follow this structure:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:main=""here is some namespace definitions">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
       <somechildelementshere />
    </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

I have this `PHP` code:

```php
// $targetDocument contains a <w:document> tag with their children
$target_body = $targetDocument->getElementsByTagNameNS($ns, 'body')[0];

// $sourceBody contains a <w:body> tag with their children
$paragraphs = $sourceBody->getElementsByTagNameNS($ns, 'p');

// $target_body is a DOMElement and $paragraph will be a DOMElement too
foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
  $target_body->importNode($paragraph, true);
}
```

And in the foreach I get `DOMException Wrong Document Error` message.

How can I add a DOMElement into another one as a child element?

Comment: `importNode` is a method of `DOMDocument`, but you are trying to use it on individual element nodes …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with the XML document and the code.  It is always better while developing to ensure that you get the code to show any errors being generated as this help in debugging.

I've changed the namespace in the document to `w` to match the namespace actually used, I've also remove the extra quote in `xmlns:main=""here` and put in a dummy URL.

For the code, you must call `importNode()` on the document you want to add it to and not an element.  Note that this also only makes the node available, it doesn't actually insert it.  Here I store the newly created node temporarily and pass it to `appendChild()` on the node in the target document where I want to add the node.

The working code is (I only use the same document as source and target for simplicity sake)...

```
$source = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://some.url">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
       <somechildelementshere />
    </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:document>';

$targetDocument = new DOMDocument();
$targetDocument->loadXML($source);
$sourceBody = new DOMDocument();
$sourceBody->loadXML($source);
$ns = "http://some.url";

$target_body = $targetDocument->getElementsByTagNameNS($ns, 'body')[0];

// $sourceBody contains a <w:body> tag with their children
$paragraphs = $sourceBody->getElementsByTagNameNS($ns, 'p');

// $target_body is a DOMElement and $paragraph will be a DOMElement too
foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
    $impParagraph = $targetDocument->importNode($paragraph, true);
    $target_body->appendChild($impParagraph);
}

echo $targetDocument->saveXML();
```